# LARAVEL: Tax Amount Not Appearing In Return Invoice Receipt But Appearing In Sale Invoice

Tags: php, laravel, invoice, tax

Tax Amount Not Appearing In Return Invoice Receipt But Appearing In Sale Invoice. Here is my tax amount code which was in the invoice file.

```
@if(!empty($receipt_details->group_tax_details))
@foreach($receipt_details->group_tax_details as $key => $value)
<tr class="color-555">
<td>
{!! $key !!}
</td>
<td class="text-right">
(+) {{$value}}
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
@else
@if( !empty($receipt_details->tax) )
<tr class="color-555">
<td>
{!! $receipt_details->tax_label !!}
</td>
<td class="text-right">
(+) {{$receipt_details->tax}}
</td>
</tr>
@endif
@endif
```

Comment: Do you use this as a include in bode files? What does `dd($receipt_details)` print?

Comment: no not using die dump dd(), tax detail appearing in sale but not in return receipt.